# Salesforce apex test class QuoteLineItem

Tags: apex, visualforce

I’am struggling to get covering percentage to 76.

The apex code

```
public class QuoteLineItemsExtension{
    
    public Quote CurrentQuote{
        get;
        set;
    }
    
    public List<QuoteLineItem> QuoteLineItems{
        get;
        set;
    }
    
    public QuoteLineItemsExtension(
        ApexPages.StandardController controller
    ){
        CurrentQuote = 
            (Quote)controller.getRecord();
            
        QuoteLineItems = 
            [
                SELECT 
                    Id, 
                    Quantity, 
                    UnitPrice 
                FROM 
                    QuoteLineItem
                WHERE 
                    QuoteId = :CurrentQuote.Id
                ORDER BY
                    LineNumber ASC
            ];
    }
    Return QuoteLineItems;

    public void SaveLineItems(){
        UPDATE QuoteLineItems;
    }
}
```

Can you help me to write a test class ?

```
@isTest static void TestQuoteLineItemsExtension() {
    // Testcode_block
}
```

Comment: Please try to implement this test class yourself and get back to StackExchange with your specific problem, if you're facing difficulties. StackExchange is not meant for searching people, who offer their Salesforce coding skills for free to others, who don't want to do their homework themselves. StackExchange is for asking specific, technical questions.

Comment: I am new to salesforce. I have to write a test case. So can some more direction to do that ?

Comment: @user3042866 A test should call your code, and use methods like `System.assert()` to verify that it's functioning, by checking that a certain condition is true or not after your code has run. There's a solid Trailhead unit on it here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing